# grpc call see body/stream of grpc call

Tags: android, sdk, grpc, grpc-python

I am using Anki Vector SDK with Python to access Anki Vector robot.
However, the SDK is limited to Python and I want to write Android apps for the Vector.
So I am trying to figure out API endpoints and their parameters together with how to use them. Unfortunately Anki has used GRPC on their SDK to access API endpoints. They also supplied some proto files to use with other languages. However, I could not understand how I can use them.

Instead, I tried GRPC tracing with the following environment variables:

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
//export GRPC_TRACE=list_tracers
//export GRPC_TRACE=all 
export GRPC_TRACE=http
```

I can get the headers for the HTTP call with this method. (example trace log below)
But I can't see the body of the HTTP call (or the streaming content)

How can I get it?

> I0105 16:40:33.658871867    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1702]   perform_stream_op[s=0x6c90b2d4]:  SEND_INITIAL_METADATA{key=3a 73 63 68 65 6d 65 ':scheme' value=68 74 74 70 73 'https', key=3a 6d 65 74 68 6f 64 ':method' value=50 4f 53 54 'POST', key=3a 61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 ':authority' value=56 65 63 74 6f 72 2d 4b 38 50 35 'Vector-K8P5', key=3a 70 61 74 68 ':path' value=2f 41 6e 6b 69 2e 56 65 63 74 6f 72 2e 65 78 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 5f 69 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 2e 45 78 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 2f 50 72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e '/Anki.Vector.external_interface.ExternalInterface/ProtocolVersion', key=61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 7a 61 74 69 6f 6e 'authorization' value=42 65 61 72 65 72 20 6e 49 6f 6f 59 43 49 68 54 51 32 30 47 7a 78 78 4c 63 2b 70 53 67 3d 3d 'Bearer nIooYCIhTQ20GzxxLc+pSg==', key=74 65 'te' value=74 72 61 69 6c 65 72 73 'trailers', key=63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 'content-type' value=61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 67 72 70 63 'application/grpc', key=75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 'user-agent' value=67 72 70 63 2d 70 79 74 68 6f 6e 2f 31 2e 31 37 2e 31 20 67 72 70 63 2d 63 2f 37 2e 30 2e 30 20 28 6c 69 6e 75 78 3b 20 63 68 74 74 70 32 3b 20 67 69 7a 6d 6f 29 'grpc-python/1.17.1 grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gizmo)', key=67 72 70 63 2d 61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 'grpc-accept-encoding' value=69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 64 65 66 6c 61 74 65 2c 67 7a 69 70 'identity,deflate,gzip', key=61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 'accept-encoding' value=69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 67 7a 69 70 'identity,gzip'} SEND_MESSAGE:flags=0x00000000:len=2 SEND_TRAILING_METADATA{} RECV_INITIAL_METADATA RECV_MESSAGE RECV_TRAILING_METADATA
>   I0105 16:40:33.659113265    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1398]   perform_stream_op_locked:  SEND_INITIAL_METADATA{key=3a 73 63 68 65 6d 65 ':scheme' value=68 74 74 70 73 'https', key=3a 6d 65 74 68 6f 64 ':method' value=50 4f 53 54 'POST', key=3a 61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 74 79 ':authority' value=56 65 63 74 6f 72 2d 4b 38 50 35 'Vector-K8P5', key=3a 70 61 74 68 ':path' value=2f 41 6e 6b 69 2e 56 65 63 74 6f 72 2e 65 78 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 5f 69 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 2e 45 78 74 65 72 6e 61 6c 49 6e 74 65 72 66 61 63 65 2f 50 72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e '/Anki.Vector.external_interface.ExternalInterface/ProtocolVersion', key=61 75 74 68 6f 72 69 7a 61 74 69 6f 6e 'authorization' value=42 65 61 72 65 72 20 6e 49 6f 6f 59 43 49 68 54 51 32 30 47 7a 78 78 4c 63 2b 70 53 67 3d 3d 'Bearer nIooYCIhTQ20GzxxLc+pSg==', key=74 65 'te' value=74 72 61 69 6c 65 72 73 'trailers', key=63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 'content-type' value=61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 67 72 70 63 'application/grpc', key=75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 'user-agent' value=67 72 70 63 2d 70 79 74 68 6f 6e 2f 31 2e 31 37 2e 31 20 67 72 70 63 2d 63 2f 37 2e 30 2e 30 20 28 6c 69 6e 75 78 3b 20 63 68 74 74 70 32 3b 20 67 69 7a 6d 6f 29 'grpc-python/1.17.1 grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gizmo)', key=67 72 70 63 2d 61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 'grpc-accept-encoding' value=69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 64 65 66 6c 61 74 65 2c 67 7a 69 70 'identity,deflate,gzip', key=61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 'accept-encoding' value=69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 67 7a 69 70 'identity,gzip'} SEND_MESSAGE:flags=0x00000000:len=2 SEND_TRAILING_METADATA{} RECV_INITIAL_METADATA RECV_MESSAGE RECV_TRAILING_METADATA; on_complete = 0x6c90b1b4
>   I0105 16:40:33.659194720    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: :scheme: https
>   I0105 16:40:33.659223208    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: :method: POST
>   I0105 16:40:33.659249145    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: :authority: Vector-K8P5
>   I0105 16:40:33.659274769    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: :path: /Anki.Vector.external_interface.ExternalInterface/ProtocolVersion
>   I0105 16:40:33.659301851    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: authorization: Bearer nIooYCIhTQ20GzxxLc+pSg==
>   I0105 16:40:33.659328569    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: te: trailers
>   I0105 16:40:33.659354193    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: content-type: application/grpc
>   I0105 16:40:33.659379036    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: user-agent: grpc-python/1.17.1 grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gizmo)
>   I0105 16:40:33.659405129    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip
>   I0105 16:40:33.659431273    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1376]   HTTP:0:HDR:CLI: accept-encoding: identity,gzip
>   I0105 16:40:33.659462991    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1187]   HTTP:CLI: Allocating new grpc_chttp2_stream 0x6c90b2d4 to id 1
>   I0105 16:40:33.659492209    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:852]    W:0x6ae19ad8 CLIENT state IDLE -> WRITING [START_NEW_STREAM]
>   I0105 16:40:33.659522468    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:852]    W:0x6ae19ad8 CLIENT state WRITING -> WRITING+MORE [SEND_MESSAGE]
>   I0105 16:40:33.659557571    2405 chttp2_transport.cc:1249]   complete_closure_step: t=0x6ae19ad8 0x6c90b1b4 refs=3 flags=0x0001 desc=op->on_complete err="No Error" write_state=WRITING+MORE
>   I0105 16:40:33.659641005    2397 writing.cc:413]             W:0x6ae19ad8 CLIENT[1] im-(sent,send)=(0,1) announce=5
>   I0105 16:40:33.659708711    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: ':authority: Vector-K8P5', elem_interned=1 [1], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.659791937    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: ':path: /Anki.Vector.external_interface.ExternalInterface/ProtocolVersion', elem_interned=0 [2], k_interned=1, v_interned=0
>   I0105 16:40:33.659828134    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'authorization: Bearer nIooYCIhTQ20GzxxLc+pSg==', elem_interned=0 [2], k_interned=0, v_interned=0
>   I0105 16:40:33.659860684    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'te: trailers', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.659891308    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'content-type: application/grpc', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.659961983    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'user-agent: grpc-python/1.17.1 grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gizmo)', elem_interned=1 [1], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.659995888    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'grpc-accept-encoding: identity,deflate,gzip', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.660025887    2397 hpack_encoder.cc:473]       Encode: 'accept-encoding: identity,gzip', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.660059531    2397 chttp2_transport.cc:1249]   complete_closure_step: t=0x6ae19ad8 0x6c90b1b4 refs=2 flags=0x0001 desc=send_initial_metadata_finished err="No Error" write_state=WRITING+MORE
>   I0105 16:40:33.660103644    2397 chttp2_transport.cc:1249]   complete_closure_step: t=0x6ae19ad8 0x6c90b1b4 refs=1 flags=0x0001 desc=send_trailing_metadata_finished err="No Error" write_state=WRITING+MORE
>   I0105 16:40:33.660134112    2397 chttp2_transport.cc:1249]   complete_closure_step: t=0x6ae19ad8 0x6c90b1b4 refs=0 flags=0x0001 desc=on_write_finished_cb err="No Error" write_state=WRITING+MORE
>   I0105 16:40:33.660166923    2397 chttp2_transport.cc:852]    W:0x6ae19ad8 CLIENT state WRITING+MORE -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
>   I0105 16:40:33.660500817    2397 chttp2_transport.cc:852]    W:0x6ae19ad8 CLIENT state WRITING -> IDLE [finish writing]
>   I0105 16:40:33.660902208    2400 chttp2_transport.cc:2609]   ipv4:192.168.254.44:443: Complete BDP ping err="No Error"
>   I0105 16:40:33.671334525    2400 parsing.cc:656]             parsing initial_metadata
>   I0105 16:40:33.671392960    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: ':status: 200', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.671427021    2400 parsing.cc:407]             HTTP:1:HDR:CLI: :status: 32 30 30 '200'
>   I0105 16:40:33.671476551    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: 'content-type: application/grpc', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.671506810    2400 parsing.cc:407]             HTTP:1:HDR:CLI: content-type: 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 67 72 70 63 'application/grpc'
>   I0105 16:40:33.671552277    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: 'trailer: Grpc-Status', elem_interned=1 [1], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.671581651    2400 parsing.cc:407]             HTTP:1:HDR:CLI: trailer: 47 72 70 63 2d 53 74 61 74 75 73 'Grpc-Status'
>   I0105 16:40:33.671617014    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: 'trailer: Grpc-Message', elem_interned=1 [1], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.671645555    2400 parsing.cc:407]             HTTP:1:HDR:CLI: trailer: 47 72 70 63 2d 4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 'Grpc-Message'
>   I0105 16:40:33.671682689    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: 'trailer: Grpc-Status-Details-Bin', elem_interned=1 [1], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.671714771    2400 parsing.cc:407]             HTTP:1:HDR:CLI: trailer: 47 72 70 63 2d 53 74 61 74 75 73 2d 44 65 74 61 69 6c 73 2d 42 69 6e 'Grpc-Status-Details-Bin'
>   I0105 16:40:33.674612891    2400 parsing.cc:661]             parsing trailing_metadata
>   I0105 16:40:33.674655858    2400 hpack_parser.cc:636]        Decode: 'grpc-status: 0', elem_interned=1 [3], k_interned=1, v_interned=1
>   I0105 16:40:33.674685597    2400 parsing.cc:503]             HTTP:1:TRL:CLI: grpc-status: 30 '0'
>   E0105 16:40:33.677045300    2396 fork_posix.cc:63]           Fork support is only compatible with the epoll1 and poll polling strategies
>   I0105 16:40:33.677160556    2396 fork_posix.cc:68]           Other threads are currently calling into gRPC, skipping fork() handlers